# python38, python3, python 2.7, and python 3.8, a file called "secretstorage" and some serious file differences

Tags: python3, python-2.7

I have Xubuntu based on 20.04.  A newish install.  My security is a VPN and the firewall from the router.

I have python2.7, python3(no decimal), and python3.8.  python3 is VERY different from the others.  It includes a folder and filed called "secretstorage" that I assumed was an easter egg.   Many files in there seem to be appended with x.egg.info.

In /etc, all three have a single file.  python3 has one marked debian_config.  The others have a file called sitecustomized.py

Under the /bin folder, python2.7 and python3.8 seem normal to my untrained eye.  python3 has a folder filled with dist-packages that looks like the install pkgs of games and emulators I got from Lutris, recently.  Many end with .egg.info and there is one called secretstorage, which originally made me laugh.  It contained what was at least one clearly a joke file(I haven't looked at the others) that pretended to be a file accidentally partially decoded.  I don't specifically remember doing a hash check, but I have been consistent about it since learning about them.

The secretstorage file has some sort of wiki entry that makes it seem legit.  There also seems to be a redirect to python2.7.1 a couple of levels inside the python3 directory that I have not taken a pic of, yet.

I have not deleted anything because I am not sure I would get it all and also for documentation.  Plus, I am not sure if it is a joke, tbh.  I have many pictures of it all, though.

So, should I delete this as malware that I somehow got from Lutris.com or perhaps a man-in-the-middle situation, I guess?

Am I being pranked, or is this a legit problem?  Some Bing searches, and a search of LinuxQuestions, as well as Ask Ubuntu find no matches to secretstorage, python38, python3(no decimal).